# Calling the result of a function in another function

Tags: python, python-3.x

The code is very long so I won't type it in.

What I am confused about as a beginner programmer, is function calling. So I had a csv file that the function divided all the content (they were integers) by 95 to get the normalised scores.

I finished the function by returning the result. its called `return sudentp_file`

Now I want to continue this new variable into another function.

So this new function will get the average of the studentp_file. So I made a new function. Ill add the other function as a template of what im doing.

```
def normalise(student_file, units_file)
~ Do stuff here ~
return studentp_file

def mean(studentp_file):


mean()
```

What I get confused about is what to put in the mean(). Do I keep it or remove it? I understand you guys don't know the file I'm working with my a little basic understanding of how functions and function calling works would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: When you call `normalise()`, get the return value to a variable and then pass that variable to `mean()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call your function you need to pass in the parameters it needs (based on what you specified in your `def` statement. So you code might look like this:

```
def normalise(student_file, units_file)
~ Do stuff here ~
    return studentp_file

def mean(studentp_file):
~ other stuff here ~
     return mean


# main code starts here

# get student file and units file from somewhere, I'll call them files A and B. Get the resulting studentp file back from the function call and store it in variable C.

C = normalize(A, B)

# now call the mean function using the file we got back from normalize and capture the result in variable my_mean

my_mean = mean(C) 

print(my_mean)
```

Answer (score 1):

i assume that normalise function is executed prior to mean function? if so try out this structure:

```
def normalise(student_file, units_file):
    #do stuff here
    return studentp_file

def mean(studentp_file):
    #do stuff here


sp_file = normalise(student_file, units_file)
mean(sp_file)
```

functions in python(2/3) are made for reusability and to keep your code organized in a block. these functions may or may not return a value, based on arguments you pass (if it accepts arguments). think of it as if functions are like real life *factories* making *finished products*. *raw goods* are fed into factories, so that they produce a finished product. functions are also like that. :)

now, notice that i assigned a variable called `sp_file` with the value of the function call `normalise(...)`. this function call - accepted parameters `(student_file, units_file)` - which are your '*raw*' goods to be fed towards your function `normalise`.

`return` - basically returns whatever value towards the point in your code which called your function. in this case return, returns the value of `studentp_file` back to `sp_file`. `sp_file` would then get `studentp_file`'s value and can be then passed to `mean()` function.

/ogs

Comment: I wanted to tick your response but both responses were good and only can tick one. Thanks, for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's unclear buy why not just (dummy example):

```
def f(a,b):
    return f2(3)+a+b
def f2(c):
    return c+1
```

Call the `f2` in `f` and do return in `f2`

Answer (score 0):

If the results from function one will always be called to function two you could do this.

```
def f_one(x, y):
    return (f_two(x, y))

def f_two(x, y):
    return x + y

print(f_one(1, 1))
```

> ```
> 2
> ```

Or just a thought... You could set up a variable `z` that works as a switch, if its `1` it passes the result to function to the next function , or if `2` returns result of function one

```
def f_one(x, y, z):
    result = x + y
    if z == 1:
        return (f_two(result))
    elif z == 2:
        return result

def f_two(x):
    return x - 1

a = f_one(1, 1, 1)
print(a)
b = f_one(1, 1, 2)
print(b)
```